# Temporary tiles cache for Mapserver

Tags: mapping, openlayers, gis, mapserver

I was searching on Google and StackOverflow to see if anyone have solution for my problem, but didn't found anyone with same problems.

So, currently I'm running Debian machine with Mapserver installed on it. The server also run webserver for displaying map data over the browser. The generation of map is dynamic, based on layers definition in database I built mapfile in PHP and based on that generated PHP the map is shown to user. The data is defined in database and as a SHP files (both combined in single mapfile).

It is fully dynamic, what I mean with that is that user can enable/disable any of layers or click inside polygon (select some points on map) it color the selection (generate new mapfile based on selection and re-generate tiles).

So the execution of all that code from selecting some area to coloring selected items somtimes take too much time for good user experience.

For solution I'd like to use some kind of temporary tiles cache, that can be used for single user, and to be able to delete it's content when user select some items on map or enable/disable one of the layers.

P.S. I already did all the optimizations provided from Mapserver documentation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please post your mapfile. What database are you using? Is it the database lookup that is slow, or the rendering, or both? How did you measure this?

Comment: Hi, the simplest map example I use contains DOF and two layers from PG database, and the mapfile looks like this: http://pastebin.com/0qb87Wgs.

Comment: I think the most time consuming tasks are processing of DOF file and reprojecting data, because al the data I use is saved in our local Gauss-Kruger projection, but then reprojected to Google's 3857 projection in which the map is shown to user. I measured mapfile generation with DEBUG option in mapfile set to 5 and lookup of processes in linux. I don't have idea how to test performance of overall process from creating mapfile to show tiles on screen.

Answer (score 0):

<s>It sounds to me like your problem is not going to be helped by server-side caching. If all of the tiles depend on user selections, then you're going to be generating a bunch of new tiles every time there's an interaction.</s>

I've been using [MapCache](http://www.mapserver.org/mapcache/%20MapCache) to solve a similar problem, where I am rendering a tileset in response to a user query. But I've broken up my tiles into multiple logical layers, and I do the compositing on the browser side. This lets me cache, server-side, the tiles for various queries, and sped up performance immensely. I did seed the cache down to zoom level 12, and I needed to use the BerkeleyDB cache type to keep from running out of inodes.

I'm using Leaflet.js for the browser-side rendering, but you should also consider OpenLayers.

---

After looking at the source code, I have some other ideas.

It looks like you're drawing each layer the same way each time. Is that right? That is, the style and predicate of a particular layer never change. Each user sees the image for that layer the same way, if they have selected the layer. But the combination of layers you show does change, based on OpenLayers control? If that's the case, you don't need per-user caching on the server. Instead, use per-layer caching, and let the user's browser figure out the client side caching.

A quick technique for finding slow layers is to turn them all of. Then reenable them one by one to find the culprit. Invoke Mapserver from the command line, and time the runs, for greater precision than you'll get by running it from your webserver.

You mentioned you're serving the images in Google 3857 while the layers are in Gauss-Kruger/EPSG 3912. Reprojecting this on the fly is expensive. Reprojecting the rasters on the fly is very expensive. If you can, you should reproject them ahead of time, and store them in 3857 (add an additional geometry column).

I don't know what a DOF file is--maybe Digital Obstacle File? Perhaps preload the DOF file into PostGIS too? That would eliminate the two pieces you think are problematic.

Take a look at the SQL queries that PostGIS is performing, and make sure those are using indexes

In any case, these individual layers should go into MapCache, in my opinion. [Here is a video of a September 2014 talk](https://vimeo.com/106868090) by the MapCache project leader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In difference to your case, nearly all the layers are dynamic, but the raster layers are static, so there could be some space for pre-caching. About multiple layers - how many layers should I have to not run into performance problems because a lot of images used in process of showing map in browser?

Comment: Assumption that the styles doesn't change are wrong, because the layer styles are changed when the user click on graphics (i.e. when user use selection tool and click inside polygon, new expression is added to mapfile, for coloring the selected polygon).

I will add additional geometry column with same projection as inside OpenLayers to see the effect, and I'll check the video, to see if MapCache could fe useful for me - currently I see it useful for already mentioned DOF (Digital Ortophoto) layers.
About debugging - I think I have to measure the whole process from user clicks to render ..

Comment: Debugging/profiling: the webserver end adds variability (server load, latency) that is irrelevant to your query/render problem. That's why I suggest leaving that out. It's just noise. Dynamic mapfile: it would help if you show us more code. Precisely what changes are made to the map/map file when user inputs change? Measurement: which layers are slow?

Comment: Ok, to be more clear about mapfile generation - layer definitions are saved in the MySQL db. When user want to color polygon inside one mapserver layer, PHP code gets the relying gid (based on click) and use it inside expression for layer style definition of mapfile. Then based on visible layers and header PHP code generates full mapfile from layer definitions in MySQL db.
For coloring single element inside layer, this code is added: http://pastebin.com/ZGAp5r7c
According to my tests with Mapserver's DEBUG functions, the slowest layers are raster layers (Ortophoto).

Comment: Sounds like you've nailed it then. Cache the orthophotos with MapCache. Or for a quick test, disable the orthophotos layer, and decide whether performance is acceptable.